# Remove Custom View from superView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have My own UIView :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MultipleSlotsClientView : UIView


-(IBAction)didPressCloseBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

And this is the implementation:

```
@implementation MultipleSlotsClientView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MultipleSlotsClientView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] retain];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = frame;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark IBAction

-(IBAction)didPressCloseBtn:(id)sender {
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

And i have a btn that connect to the `didPressCloseBtn` method and when i press the button the method called but the View won't remove from the superview.

This is how i alloc the UIView and add it:

```
MultipleSlotsClientView *multiView = [[[MultipleSlotsClientView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:multiView];
```

Any idea why the view won't disappear?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot same as my screenshot below?

Comment: can you log the superview? `NSLog("%@", self.superview) inside the IBAction

Comment: It is always a good practice to place NSLog inside your callbacks to check whether it is getting called or not. So as Daij asked.

Comment: where the button with event `didPressCloseBtn` is placed? inside `MultipleSlotsClientView` or inside other viewcontroller where you are adding `MultipleSlotsClientView`?

Comment: Your init method will cause a memory leak as you don't use ARC.

Comment: Can you try with: 
        self=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"educationInfoView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

Comment: Please share the piece of code where you actually connect the IBAction with your programmatically created instance multiView.

Comment: Ok i found the problem, the View was not connect good in the interface builder. @Hermann Klecker why there will be leak?

Comment: The caller allocates a MultipleSlotsClientView object and calls init on it. The first thing that init does is creating an object, too, by calling loadNibNamed which allocates another MultipleSlotsClientView object, overwriting the self reference with the new object and then returns this to the caller. I do not need a crystal ball to say that the caller will overwrite his only reference to the newly (and now unused) instance. Bottom line, you allocated two objects and use only one of them. With ARC this is just bad style. Without it is a leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to connect like below screenshot, don't connect to FileOwner.[image]

Comment: Where is the 'below screenshot' ?

Comment: this isnt an answer... just asking is your IBAction called ok would have sufficed as a comment

Comment: IBOutlet is not only the issue.. If it is from CustomView and if you are connecting it to ViewController. This is what he is explaining. He is just telling that make your IBOutlet connection to the CustomView

Comment: Yes, i'm telling that set CustomClass reference as MultipleSlotsClientView, but do not set file's owner reference as MultipleSlotsClientView.

Comment: Looks like company policy is blocking screenshots :(

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 write the below method in NSObject Category class

```
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)NibName {
    NSObject *cl = nil;
    if (NSClassFromString(NibName) != nil) {
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NibName owner:self options:nil];
        for (id cls in arr) {
            if([cls isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(NibName)])
            {
                cl = cls;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cl;
}
```

Step:2 call the respective Class like

```
MultipleSlotsClientView *multiView = [MultipleSlotsClientView loadNibNamed:@"MultipleSlotsClientView"]
[self.view addSubview:multiView];
```

And No need to write anything in "initWithFrame". 
Try this. It may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to a comment. Just because you cannot format comments nicely. It is about why you leak memory in your code and how you could write the code to overcome the issue.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Do something here if you have to.
        // Currently there is no reason for overwriting intiWithFrame: at all. 

    }
    return self;
}
```

And instead of:

```
MultipleSlotsClientView *multiView = [[[MultipleSlotsClientView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
```

Just do:

```
MultipleSlotsClientView *multiView= [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MultipleSlotsClientView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] autorelease];
multiView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Well, whether you should retain or autorelease it or nothing of that kind at all depends on the other code. Assuming that you add multiView to the subview hierarchy, which will retain it, autorelease is fine.